# XBOX ONE - After update, snapped YouTube runs poorly

Tags: xbox-one

After doing a recent system update, I can no longer run a game and YouTube at the same time.
I can have it snapped, but the video runs at about half a frame per second and it causes my console to run sluggish in the menus. The audio runs fine, as does the game I'm playing.
I'm asking this because when I first got my console I could run both fine. I've only used 13% of the HDD too so I doubt it's that.
It may not have been the update, and it might just be a coincidence. If there is a way to get it to run better I'd love to know, or is it like this for everyone?

Comment: Try resetting your router and modem.

Comment: Are you part of the beta?